# Regex to match words in a paragraph but exclude inner HTML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I'm using a regex I found on stackoverflow to surround word instances in a paragraph with a span tag such that a user can click on each inner word to see that word's definition. This works perfectly, however, the issue I've run into is that sometimes the paragraph has phrases of words which are wrapped in an inner  or  tag, e.g. a title.

Works:

```
<div id="passage"> 
<p>
    Hello, my name is SirTophamHatt.
</p>
...
</div>

$('#passage').find('p').each(function() {
    $(this).html(function (index, oldHtml) {
        return oldHtml.replace(/\b(\w+?)\b/g, '<span class="word">$1</span>');
    });
});

<div id="passage">
<p>
    <span class="word">Hello</span>, <span class="word">my</span> <span class="word">name</span> <span class="word">is</span> <span class="word">SirTophamHatt</span>.
</p>
...
</div>
```

Does not work:

```
<div id="passage"> 
<p>
    <em>Hello, my name is SirTophamHatt.</em>
</p>
...
</div>

$('#passage').find('p').each(function() {
    $(this).html(function (index, oldHtml) {
        return oldHtml.replace(/\b(\w+?)\b/g, '<span class="word">$1</span>');
    });
});

<div id="passage">
<p>
    <
    <span class="word">em</span>
    >
    <span class="word">Hello</span>, 
    <span class="word">my</span> 
    <span class="word">name</span> 
    <span class="word">is</span> 
    <span class="word">SirTophamHatt</span>
    <!--<span class="word">-->em>
</p>
...
</div>
```

I separated the last paragraph for clarity.

I'm not great with regex; how can I modify the pattern such that it will match all words which are not starting or closing HTML tags?

Thanks!

EDIT: The words within the child elements must get the  wrapped around it. The HTML tags themselves must be ignored.

EDIT2: Rushed the example, did not provide proper use of string replace.

Comment: `$('#passage').replace(` doesn't do what you think it does. (`$.fn.replace` doesn't exist)

Comment: You're right, I oversimplified my post:

Should be 
$('#passage').find('p').each(function() {       $(this).html(function(index, oldHtml) { 
return oldHtml.replace(/\b(\w+?)\b/g, '<span class="word">$1</span>');
                            });
                        });

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead to make sure there's no closing angled bracket ahead of the word without an opening angled bracket:

```
\b(\w+(?![^<>]*>))\b
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And I think you can safely remove the `?` in `\w+?`, since you're matching whole words.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to wrap the words using a highlight plugin i wrote a while back.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bfXPy/

```
$("#passage").highlightText(/\b([a-z]+)\b/ig,"word")
```

you may need to upgrade the `([a-z]+)` portion to match what's contained in the text you're replacing.

The idea is to iterate over the text nodes rather than dealing with html replacement.